# Javascript Writing to PDF or Excel

Tags: html, local-storage

Hey Related to your answer on [Can I write files with HTML5/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309958/can-i-write-files-with-html5-js)

How would I modify this for say Excel or PDF. I tried but was unable to get it to work. I get a corrupt file downloaded when I change MIME to application/pdf

I am trying to link it to data stored in localstorage which I have all in a variable.

My current code is:

```
function setSaveFile(contents, file_name, mime_type) {

  var a = document.getElementById('save');
  mime_type = mime_type || 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'; // text/html, image/png, et c
  if (file_name) a.setAttribute('Log.xls', file_name);
  a.href = 'data:'+ mime_type +';base64,'+ btoa(contents || 'Description' + '   ' + 'Notes' + ' ' + 'Date\n\n' + pdftimeLog);
}
```

I want to be able to export it as a CSV with each of those headings: DATE, description, notes in different cells. I want it mobile friendly.Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent Options for CSV Everyone:

http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

[Is it possible to use any HTML5 fanciness to export local storage to Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286423/is-it-possible-to-use-any-html5-fanciness-to-export-local-storage-to-excel)

http://css-tricks.com/localstorage-examples/

[Local Storage manipulation and possible sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672727/local-storage-manipulation-and-possible-sending)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a file to be a valid pdf or excelfile their contents need to conform to the standard that defines the respective format, just changing mimetypes won't do much good.

For PDF there's a library [jspdf](http://jspdf.com/) that might work for you.

I haven't seen a solution for Excel yet, it will be a whole lot harder as the (xls) file format is quite complicated, for the time being it's probably preferable to generate the file on the server.

Comment: If you only need to open it as a spread sheet, you could also produce a *.csv file, a comma seperated value file.

Comment: If I opt for CSV how would it work. Currently I am storing data in localstorage. I want to make it so that this data can be exported and emailed by users and I suppose csv will do. The software is intended for mobile use thus, downloadify is not an option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to CSV, it's also possible to write an Excel file by writing HTML  to a file with a .xls extension.  Excel opens it up based on the extension.  Haven't yet explored how deeply it can paginate, format.